# doesn't do a loop.. adding timespan from mssql database

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

i need help for this code.. it is succesfully added but it doesnt loop from each database record.. i have 3 records in my DB but he only detects 1 and i use loop.. it does not loop and add to it.. any help to revise this code?

i have 3 records from fieldname: dtr_grantotal:

1. = 10:41:00
2. = 01:11:00
3. = 03:30:10

   ```
   sqlSTR = "select * from tblTImelog where dtr_datelog Between '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "'"
   ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)

   _totalDays = sqlDT.Rows.Count

   If sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
       Dim T1 As String = "00:00:00"
       Dim myRow As DataRow = sqlDT.Rows(sqlDT.Rows.Count - 1)
       Dim span1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(T1)

       For i = 0 To sqlDT.Rows.Count - 1
           Dim span2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(sqlDT.Rows(i)("dtr_grandtotal"))
           t1 = span1.Add(span2).ToString
       Next 

       MsgBox(t1)
   End If
   ```

   he only shows from my msgbox the first.. although i added it in my for loop..

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `t1` each time. Do this instead:

```
For i = 0 To sqlDT.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim span2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(sqlDT.Rows(i)("dtr_grandtotal"))
    span1 = span1.Add(span2)
Next 

t1 = span1.ToString
MsgBox(t1)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Don't forget, if this answer helped you, you can mark it as "correct" by clicking the tick mark beside it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369

Answer (score 0):

replace your For Loop with this:

```
 For i = 0 To sqlDT.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim span2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(sqlDt.Rows(i)("dtr_grandtotal").ToString)
            span1 = span1.Add(span2)
        Next

        MsgBox(span1.ToString)
```